# Use Automator for handling multiple file inputs through shell Cat command in OS X to combine videos

Tags: macos, video-conversion, video-editing, automator

I'm trying to do a similar thing with video files with no luck. Tried:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    cat "$f" > ~/Desktop/Test.mov
done
```

When I do this it just puts the last file selected in the file.

Comment: Ref of the Cat command for video. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135157/terminal-tool-to-join-mp4-videos

Answer (score 0):

As the article you linked points out, the `cat` method doesn't entirely work; use a better tool.

As for the direct question, the `>` redirection sends output to a file, *replacing any previous contents*. Thus, the second file replaces the first, then the third replaces the second, ... and eventually the last one replaces the next-to-last. If `cat` were a viable way to do this, you could either 1) blank the file first, then use the `>>` redirection, 2) use the `>` redirection but put it after `done` so it redirects the entire loop, or 3) just use `cat "$@" >~/Desktop/Test.mov` and let `cat` do the iteration itself.

The [linked question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/135157/terminal-tool-to-join-mp4-videos) suggests using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install an appropriate tool, and then use something like:

```
mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -idx -o ~/Desktop/Test.mov "$@"
```

Or use `ffmpeg` and some shell `IFS` hackery to get the file list in its preferred format:

```
IFS="|"
ffmpeg -i concat:"$*" -codec copy output.mp4
```

BTW, messing with `IFS` can lead to really weird bugs. In this case the script is simple enough that it shouldn't cause trouble, but I don't recommend it in larger scripts, unless you use safety measures to limit side effects.